# Forming dynamically request for xpath, problem with quotes

Tags: python, xpath, lxml, quotes

I have some problems with lxml which does not preserve the original file, for example if I have an xml file which contains:

```
  <column caption='Choix Découpage'   name='[Aujourd&apos;Hui Parameter (copy 2)]'>
            <alias key='&quot;Frais de Services&quot;' value='Offline Fees' />
  </column>
```

and I take a glance at the key attribute of alias node

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print([node.attrib['key'] for node in root.xpath("//alias")]) # we get ['"Billetterie Ferroviaire"']
value = [node.attrib['key'] for node in root.xpath("//alias")][0]
```

Now if I want to retrieve all the alias nodes with the attribute '"Billetterie Ferroviaire"' I can do (solution given in another post, thanks again):

```
root.xpath("//alias[@key='\"Frais de Services\"']")
```

But imagine that I want to dynamically form the query:

```
"//alias[@key='\"Frais de Services\"']"
```

but Python uses simple quote for strings, so I can't write exactly this query. Maybe xpath understand other equivalent form? I am a bit lost if someone could explain me why Python use simple Quote and what can I do to solve such problems (is there always alternative ways when I want to generate a string for an other program to feed it with a good structure). Hope to be clear enough to be helped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply escape those apostrophes which you don't want Python to interpret as closing the string:

```
 test = 'string which contains \'apostrophes\''
```

The variable `test` will contain the following string:

```
string which contains 'apostrophes'
```

I'm not sure how to explain why Python is using apostrophes to enclose strings. It's simply a decision made by the language designers. Strings can be enclosed in both apostrophes or double quotes and usually, it's a good idea to use those which don't appear in the string they're enclosing (or there's less of them), so you don't need to escape them:

```
test = "string with 'apostrophes'"
test = 'string with "double quotes"'
test = 'string with both \'apostrophes\' and "double quotes"'
```

Comment: @curious Did it help?